# Cannot find field by use of withHint() - using Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am doing Espresso automation, but cannot find a text field using the `withHint`. This is the layout params:

```
MaterialEditText{ 
   id=12,
   visibility=VISIBLE,
   width=881,
   height=253,
   has-focus=false,
   has-focusable=true,
   has-window-focus=true,
   is-clickable=true,
   is-enabled=true,
   is-focused=false,
   is-focusable=true,
   is-layout-requested=false,
   is-selected=false,
   layout-params=android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams@510370b,
   tag=null,
   root-is-layout-requested=false,
   has-input-connection=true,
   editor-info=[ 
      inputType=0x20001 imeOptions=0x4c000005 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=First name * label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null hintLocales=null contentMimeTypes=null
   ],
   x=0.0,
   y=0.0,
   text=,
   hint=First name *,
   input-type=131073,
   ime-target=false,
   has-links=false
}
```

Espresso statement is as follows

```
onView(ViewMatchers.withHint("First name *")).perform(typeText("SomeName"), closeSoftKeyboard());
```

Comment: Is the parent of `MaterialEditText` a `TextInputLayout`?

Comment: No. It's a RelativeLayout